# compare with previous and next input fields

Tags: javascript

For example, if the user enters 5 in the previous text box, the user can only input greater than 7 in the next input because in between previous input and next input I need at least 2 numbers gap or more than that please anyone helps me.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> </head> 
<body> 
<form action="../" onsubmit="return checknumber(this);">
 <input type="number" name="year1" size="20" maxlength="20"> <br> <br> 
<input type="number" name="year2" size="20" maxlength="20"> <br> 
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Send Address!">
</form>

 <script> function checknumber(theForm) { 
if (theForm.year1.value > theForm.year2.value) { 
alert('Those enter more than 2'); return false;
 } else { return true; }
 } 
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you need to check the values in the text boxes to make sure they are at least 2 apart - hope that helps

Comment: Please share code that you have done yet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: but it is accepting any number after the previous input but i need the output like example i enter 4 in previous input in next input it should be 6 or more than 6 but not less than 6 i need in that way plz can you help me

Comment: Why you take it from user you can add that dynamically!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post new answer for you, in which you can update as per your requirement.
you may also need to refer [Javascript tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-html-dom-events) which may helpful to learn JavaScript with HTML easily.

try below:

```js
function checknumber() {   
 var txt1=parseInt(document.getElementsByName('year1')[0].value);
 var txt2=parseInt(document.getElementsByName('year2')[0].value);
 var lblErr=document.getElementById('lblForYearError');
 if(txt2<(txt1+2))
 {
    lblErr.textContent='Value is less then +2'
 }
 else if(txt2>(txt1+2))
 {
     lblErr.textContent='Value is more then +2'
 }
 else
 {
     lblErr.textContent='';
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html> <html>
    <head> </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="../" onsubmit="return checknumber(this);">            <input type="number" name="year1" size="20" maxlength="20">                                           <br> <br>
       <input type="number" name="year2" size="20" maxlength="20" oninput="checknumber(this);"><label id='lblForYearError' style='font-color:red;'></label>
       <br> 
       <input type="SUBMIT" value="Send Address!">
       </form>  </body> 
       </html>
```

Comment: u r a genius sir

Comment: can we use document.getElementbyId in the place of name

Comment: i have ticked the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are to close to answer as you commented.

just need to improve your `if` condition and parse data from `string` to `int`,

please change `theForm.year1.value > theForm.year2.value` from  `if (theForm.year2.value != (theForm.year1.value+2))`:

try below:

```js
function checknumber(theForm) {   
 if (parseInt(theForm.year2.value) != (parseInt(theForm.year1.value)+2)) 
    { 
    alert('Those enter more than 2');
            return false;
            } 
     return true;
            
}
```

```html
<!doctype html> <html>
    <head> </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="../" onsubmit="return checknumber(this);">            <input type="number" name="year1" size="20" maxlength="20">                                           <br> <br>
       <input type="number" name="year2" size="20" maxlength="20">
       <br> 
       <input type="SUBMIT" value="Send Address!">
       </form>  </body> 
       </html>
```

Comment: sir one more doubt that adding 2 will be the default one but if i enter more than 2 also it should accept and i have tried by using > symbol also but iam failed so can you explain me how

Comment: If more than `2` than you need `<` not `>`

Comment: Pls choose appropriate operator based on your condition

Comment: shal i put that <> the middle of that if

Comment: please refer [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: iam having one more doubt caan i ask

Comment: you can ask another question as you doubt

Comment: and comment link here

Comment: yesterday you have sent me a code that is with alert actually i dont want to show alert because for alert we should submit button so just i want to make changes that while iam entering the number in the next input if it is less than 2 it show show message that its less than 2 without pressing the button it should show message while entering the data

Comment: please check new answer

Comment: sir actually the logic is working only once in the code if i add more input fields  the logic is not eshowing any effect

Comment: sir i am having a doubt 0


I am trying to put some inputs for example if i enter the first input box only then i should be able to text in next input box or else it should show error message

Comment: i think you have to ask a new question and comment link here